# Ajax recursive function work strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

Hello guys here's my code:

```
var ajax={
    chiamata:function(target,url,opzioni){
        if (!tools.array_key_exists('caricamento',opzioni)){
            opzioni['caricamento']=1;
        }
        var dati=url.split('?');
        $.ajax({
            type: opzioni['type'],
            url: url,
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: dati[1],
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){
                if (opzioni['caricamento']!=0){
                    ajax.printLoading();
                }
                $(target).html(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Chiamata fallita!");
            }
        })  
    },
    printLoading:function(){
        var body="#colonnaDX";
        $(body).ajaxStart(function(){
            $(body).append('<div id="loading"><img src="graphic/IMAGE/spinner.gif"/>Loading...</div>');
        })
        .ajaxStop(function(){
            $('#loading').remove(); 
        });
    }
},        
//Recursive function
var object={
    checkAzione:function(target,url,opzioni,interval){
        if (!interval)
            interval=60000;
        ajax.chiamata(target,url,opzioni);
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.checkAzione(target,url,opzioni,interval);
        }, interval);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    object.checkAzione(
        '#colonnaDX',
        'someactions.php',{
            'caricamento':0
        },
        10000
    );
})
```

I'll try to explain the problem as better as i can, When the document is ready, the function "checkAzione" starts and it makes some stuff like DB calls etc, this kinds of ajax calls don't need any visual loading like spinner etc so in the array "opzioni" i set a flag 'caricamento':0 (same of 'loading':0) just check my ajax object to see what i mean, it works until i make some ajax calls that using 'caricamento':1, from that moment every ajax calls in my recursive function makes the "printLoading"... Any tips????

Comment: When you bind an event to ajaxStop and ajaxStart, it doesn't go away until you remove the element you bound it to or you unbind those events. It would be better to use beforeSend and complete to show and hide the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are *global*, you add them to the body. You probably shouldn't use `ajaxStart/Stop` in this case, just add the functionality to your ajax listeners (success and error).